# Excel VBA copying rows in For loop

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks for help.

I am trying to copy some rows to a new sheet and will be adding some conditions later on, but wanted to get the basics right.

I want to copy the 4th row on the wsCurrent Sheet to the 1st row on the wsReview Sheet, and then copy rows 5-200 on to that sheet too. Eventually I will be having the for loop skip based on criteria so it is only certain rows that are copied.

The first part of copying the 4th row works fine, but the for loop throws errors and doesn't do what I expect, for example, it takes the "j" as the column reference, rather than the value and if I try and use a more complex column reference, then it won't compile.

```
Sub exportForReview()
Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
Set wbCurrent = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsReview As Worksheet
Set wsReview = wbCurrent.Worksheets("ExportForReview")
Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
Set wsCurrent = wbCurrent.Worksheets("Master")
Dim j As Integer
j = 2

wsCurrent.Range("4:4").Copy
wsReview.Range("1:1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
wsReview.Range("1:1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

For i = 5 To 200
    wsCurrent.Cells(i).EntireRow.Copy
    wsReview.Cells(j).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    wsReview.Cells(j).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    j = j + 1

Next i    
End Sub
```

I also tried

```
    For i = 5 To 200
    wsCurrent.Range("i:i").Copy
    wsReview.Range("j:j").EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    wsReview.Range("j:j").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    j = j + 1

Next i
```

There seems to be an issue trying to use variables inside the code to select and copy the row, can anyone advise?

Comment: How about `wsReview.Cells(j,1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial` ? Do you really need to copy the whole row? And why not do it in one go?

Comment: I see your point, I need to copy the whole row of the table, rather than the whole row of the sheet, so yes, I will use the range as suggested in the below to resolve that feedback point. In addition, I will be iterating through checking if some data is present within the particular row, and if not, skipping and not copying it. As I mentioned, this was just the basic bit and I am going to add some conditions so it skips, hope that's clear and thank you so much for getting back to me and giving me the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're so close :)

Change this part:

```
For i = 5 To 200
    wsCurrent.Cells(i).EntireRow.Copy
    wsReview.Cells(j).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    wsReview.Cells(j).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    j = j + 1
Next i
```

to this:

```
For i = 5 To 200
    wsCurrent.Rows(i).Copy
    wsReview.Rows(j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    wsReview.Rows(j).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    j = j + 1
Next i
```

Friendly tip, is to consider to define the range!
example:

```
wsCurrent.Range(wsCurrent.Cells(i, "A"), wsCurrent.Cells(i, "DA")).Copy 
wsReview.Range(wsReview.Cells(i, "A"), wsReview.Cells(i, "DA")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

It's large amount of data that you want to copy and paste which in large workbook will slow down the performance considerably. You'll propbably have "not responding" for a short time when you run the code.

`Cells(row, column)` wants a row and column value while `rows()` or `columns()` only needs a single value :)

Comment: You can use `Cells` with a single argument, but e.g. `cells(3).address` will return C1 rather than A3.

Comment: Thanks worked a treat and thanks for defining range, yes it did take a while to process the code. So glad I was close, always feel like I'll be told off for posting an obvious question on here!